# How to connect a 5volt relay to esp32?

Tags: power, relay, esp32, 5v, 3.3v

Sorry to ask this stupid question here. I have the relay shown below with me. its a 5 volt relay. I wonder can it operate on 3 volts. If so, is it possible to connect it to the esp32 3 volt output. or there is a way around.

https://robu.in/product/1-channel-isolated-5v-relay-module-opto-coupler-for-arduino-pic-avr-dsp-arm/
[image]

Comment: Hi Savad, if you have 5 Volts available, try one of these: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=5v+relay+from+3.3v

Comment: how do you know that it does not work with 3.3 V? ... 5 V rating may just be the maximum allowable voltage

Comment: the circuit is probably similar to https://circuitdigest.com/sites/default/files/circuitdiagram/4-channel-relay-driver-module-circuit.png ... it requires 0 V input to activate the relay ... reducing the current limiting resistor, or removing the indicator LED should make it work with 3.3 V LED supply

Comment: it is a relay module. it may work with 5 V powering and 3.3 V logic signal

Comment: @Juraj. Yes its a relay module.It saying its a 5v realy module. My question is can i power it with with 3.3 Vcc Out of esp32

Comment: you have to power it with 5 V. how do you power the esp32?

Comment: According to the ESP datasheet (esp-wroom-32se) the I/O pins can source 40 mA and sink 28 mA. That is not enough to connect the relay directly to an I/O pin. The SRD-05VDC-SL-C relay needs 71.4 mA current.  
When you use a transistor, you will lose an extra 0.6V leaving 2.7V to switch the relay. I don't expect that to work but you can try to make the relay switch on a bench power supply set to 2.7 V.  
If you have an ESP development board, you might be able to use the 5V from the USB and a transistor to switch the relay. (don't forget the diode over the coil)